# multiple controllers and files in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I have multiple controllers in multiple files.
on one page I use two controllers.

Now I get the error `'&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined'`

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('demo', ['MainControllers', 'MainServices'])
    .constant('myConfig', {
        'backend': 'http://localhost:7645',
});
```

controller 1:

```
angular.module('MainControllers', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('DemoOneController', function($scope, $rootScope, $modal, mainService) {
```

Controller 2:

```
angular.module('MainControllers', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('DemoTwoController', function($scope, $rootScope, $modal, mainService) {
```

controller 3:

```
angular.module('MainControllers', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $log) {
```

what is wrong?

Comment: you don't need to add the dependencies multiple times, just once: `angular.module('MainControllers').controller("...")`

Comment: or you could do this: app.controller("");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when u use `angular.module('MainControllers', ['ui.bootstrap'])` will override the previous module you define with `MainControllers` name. you need only one definition of the module so u can do like this,

```
angular.module('MainControllers', ['ui.bootstrap'])
  .controller('DemoOneController', function($scope, $rootScope, $modal, mainService) {

angular.module('MainControllers')
   .controller('DemoTwoController', function($scope, $rootScope, $modal, mainService) {

angular.module('MainControllers')
    .controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $log) {
```

removing `, ['ui.bootstrap']` from second and third controllers will solve the overriding issue,

when angular finds module dependency array with or without empty like

`angular.module('MainControllers', [])` //without dependency

`angular.module('MainControllers', ['ui.bootstrap'])` //with dependency

it will override the module.

if you do like  `angular.module('MainControllers').controller('Mo`....` //without dependency array

it will check for the module with the name `MainControllers` which is already defined and assign the `controller` to that module.

here is the demo [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6BWw6Nr9lv2uyRrLx5XA?p=preview)

Comment: now 'DemoTwoController' gives error: 
`"0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.19/$injector/nomod?p0=MainControllers"`